# How to get mongoDB aggregated month wise data using java

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here is my data in db.

```
"Accounts" : [ 
        {
            "Total_Credits" : 4000,
            "Total_Debits" : 0,
            "Date" : "25-05-2015"
        }, 
        {
            "Total_Credits" : 1000,
            "Total_Debits" : 0,
            "Date" : "26-05-2015"
        }, 
        {
            "Total_Credits" : 1000,
            "Total_Debits" : 0,
            "Date" : "10-07-2015"
        }]
```

I want to extract sum of total credits and debits month wise.
I want to do it in java.

Comment: Well, get started then!

Comment: please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: First you should show your work around... Additionally, You stored date as string. if you store it as unix timestamp then it is possible to group data monthwise by using mongo aggregation and combination of different mongodb operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** with following aggregation pipeline (Mongo shell implementation):

```
db.ledger.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$Accounts"
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "Total_Credits" : "$Accounts.Total_Credits",
            "Total_Debits" : "$Accounts.Total_Debits",
            "month_year" : {  "$substr": [ "$Accounts.Date", 3, -1 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$month_year",
            "Total_Credits": { "$sum": "$Total_Credits" },
            "Total_Debits": { "$sum": "$Total_Debits" }
        }
    }
])
```

With the example above, this outputs to console:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "07-2015",
            "Total_Credits" : 1000,
            "Total_Debits" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "05-2015",
            "Total_Credits" : 5000,
            "Total_Debits" : 0
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

With Java, this can be implemented as follows:

```
import com.mongodb.AggregationOutput;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;

public class Aggregation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DB db = MongoDb.getAccountsDb();
        DBCollection ledger = db.getCollection("ledger");

        //------------------------------------------------- aggregation framework

        DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$Accounts");
        List<Object> substrList = Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"$Accounts.Date", 3, -1});
        DBObject monthProjection = new BasicDBObject("$substr", substrList);
        DBObject projectFields = new BasicDBObject("Total_Credits", "$Accounts.Total_Credits");
        projectFields.put("Total_Debits", "$Accounts.Total_Debits");
        projectFields.put("month_year", monthProjection);
        DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", projectFields );

        DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$month_year");
        groupFields.put("Total_Credits", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", "$Total_Credits"));
        groupFields.put("Total_Debits", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", "$Total_Debits"));
        DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

        AggregationOutput output = ledger.aggregate( unwind, project, group );

        System.out.println("\n" + output);
    }

}
```

Comment: Such a good answer for such a poorly asked question. You're too good hearted...

Comment: can we search documents using id basis.

Comment: @San Yes, you would need a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator in the aggregation pipeline that filters/searches the documents by a given identifier expression or criteria and should be the first pipeline stage.

Comment: means my above json is depend on accountID....from above code i'm getting all accountID 's embedded Account details..so i want to fetch data  only particular accountID.

Comment: {
"Account_ID"=1,
"Accounts" : [ 
        {
            "Total_Credits" : 4000,
            "Total_Debits" : 0,
            "Date" : "25-05-2015"
        }, 
        {
            "Total_Credits" : 1000,
            "Total_Debits" : 0,
            "Date" : "26-05-2015"
        }, 
        {
            "Total_Credits" : 1000,
            "Total_Debits" : 0,
            "Date" : "10-07-2015"
        }]  
} my json data like this i want to fetch data using Accout_ID.

Comment: @San Can you please read this first [**How do I ask a good question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as I would encourage you to create a new question that encompasses all the tenets from the link above and that describes the issue you are trying to solve, what you have tried and what you expect.

Comment: Thanks you i got the result..

Comment: deserves many more upvotes.